# How to attach an html to a div, with javascript expression inside?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use innerHtml property to attach an html with javascript expression to a div.
But I get to see output as only [object]. How to achieve it? The code is below...

```
document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = <ul>{userInfo.map((name, id) => <li><Link to="userpage?id="{...id}>{name}</Link></li>)}</ul>
```

Here UserInfo is an array of objects. Is there any other way to do the thing? how?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML =`

  ${userInfo.map((name, id) => "
- <Link to="userpage?id="{...id}>{name}
  )}

`

Answer (score 0):

try the String()
`<Link to="userpage?id="{...id}>{String(name)}</Link>`